# How to assign scipy.sparse matrix to NumPy array via indexing?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

When I try to assign a [`scipy.sparse`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/sparse.html) matrix `s` (any of the available sparse types) to a NumPy array `a` like this:

```
a[:] = s
```

I get a `TypeError`:

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Is there a way to get around this?

I know about the `todense()` and `toarray()` methods, but I'd really like to avoid the unnecessary copy and I'd prefer to use the same code for both NumPy arrays and SciPy sparse matrices.
For now, I'm not concerned with getting the values from the sparse matrix being inefficient.

Is there probably some kind of wrapper around sparse matrices that works with NumPy indexing assignment?

If not, any advice how I could build such a thing by myself?

Is there a different sparse array library that cooperates with NumPy in this situation?

**UPDATE:**

I poked around in the NumPy sources and, searching for the error message string, I think I found the section where the indexing assignment happens in [`numpy/core/src/multiarray/arraytypes.c.src` around line 187](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/arraytypes.c.src#L187) in the function `@TYPE@_setitem()`.

I still don't really get it, but at some point, the `float()` function seems to be called (if `a` is a floating-point array). So I tried to monkey-patch one of the SciPy sparse matrix classes to allow this function to be called:

```
import scipy
s = scipy.sparse.dok_matrix((5, 1))
def myfloat(self):
    assert self.shape == (1, 1)
    return self[0, 0]
scipy.sparse.dok.dok_matrix.__float__ = myfloat
a[:] = s
```

Sadly, this doesn't work because `float()` is called on the whole sparse matrix and not on the individual items thereof.

So I guess my new question is: how can I further change the sparse matrix class to make NumPy iterate over all the items and call `float()` on each of them?

**ANOTHER UPDATE:**

I found a sparse array module on Github (https://github.com/FRidh/sparse), which allows assignment to a NumPy array. Sadly, the features of the module are quite limited (e.g. slicing doesn't really work yet), but it might help to understand how assigning to NumPy arrays can be achieved.
I'll investigate that further ...

**YET ANOTHER UPDATE:**

I did some more digging and found that a more interesting source file is probably [`numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c).
I suspect that the function `PySequence_Check()` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/c-api/sequence.html#c.PySequence_Check)/[code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c71e8b81f1f4d349d1a24a6fe162cbbecedff8f0/Objects/abstract.c#L1370)) is called sometime during the assignment. The simple sparse array class from https://github.com/FRidh/sparse passes the test, but it looks like the sparse matrix classes from SciPy don't (although in my opinion they are sequences).

They get checked for `__array_struct__`, `__array_interface__` and `__array__`, and then it's somehow decided that they are not sequences.
The attributes `__getitem__` and `__len__` (which all the sparse array classes have!) are not checked.

This leads me to yet another question: How can I manipulate the sparse matrix classes (or objects thereof) in a way that they pass `PySequence_Check()`?

I think as soon as they are recognized as sequences, assignment should work, because `__getitem__()` and `__len__()` should be sufficient for that.

Comment: What is `s`?  How was `a` created?  What sparse format?  Dtype?

Comment: For example, like this: `s = scipy.sparse.dok_matrix((4, 5))`, so it would be *Dictionary Of Keys* format and dtype would be `float64`. I also tried other sparse formats and they don't work either. If I use an integer `dtype` in `a`, the error message is slightly different: "TypeError: long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dok_matrix'".

Comment: If I use `lil_matrix`, the error message is "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.".

Comment: @hpaulj: Yes, `a[:]=s.A` does what I want, but it creates a new temporary array, which I would like to avoid. Another problem with it is that `s.A` will now *only* work with sparse arrays and not anymore with "normal" NumPy arrays, so i would have more code paths and I'd need some kind of `isinstance()` check to decide which path to go. And yes, I also want to insert all the zeros.

Comment: Assuming the sparse matrix is a 'sequence', what values should it produce when iterated over?  Just the non-zeros, or all (as though it were dense)?

Comment: For what I want, it should also produce the zeros. This would be really helpful for generic code. But I just realized that a sparse *matrix* cannot be used for my use case. I need something that looses a dimension when indexed with one index. The resulting thing can be indexed again and yields my float values (and not a 1x1 *matrix*). So I really need a sparse *array*. I will check if I can modify the sparse array class from https://github.com/FRidh/sparse for my needs, are there any other sparse *array* libraries available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment to my question, the sequence interface won't work for sparse *matrices*, because they don't lose a dimension when indexed with a single number.
To try it anyway, I created a very limited quick-and-dirty sparse *array* class in pure Python, which, when indexed with a single number, returns a "row" class (which holds a view to the original data), which again can be indexed with a single number to yield the actual value at this index. Using an instance `s` of my class, assigning to a NumPy array `a` works exactly as requested:

```
a[:] = s
```

I expected this to be somewhat inefficient, but it is really, really, really, extremely slow. Assigning a 500.000 x 100 sparse array took several minutes!
The good news, though, is that no full-sized temporary array is created during the assignment. The memory usage stays about constant during the assignment (while one of the CPUs maxes out).

So this is basically one solution to the original question.

To make the assignment more efficient and still use no temporary copy of the dense array data, NumPy would have to internally do something similar to

```
s.toarray(out=a)
```

As far as I know, there is currently no way to get NumPy to do that.

However, there is a way to do something very similar, by providing an `__array__()` method that returns a NumPy array. Incidentally, SciPy sparse matrices already have such a method, just with a different name: `toarray()`. So I just renamed it:

```
scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.__array__ = scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.toarray
a[:] = s
```

This works like a charm (also with the other sparse matrix classes) and is totally fast!

According to my limited understanding of the situation, this should create a temporary NumPy array with the same size as `a` which holds all the values from `s` (and many zeros) and which is then assigned to `a`.
But strangely, even when I use a very large `a` that occupies nearly all my available RAM, the assignment still happens very quickly and no additional RAM is used.

So I guess this is another, much better solution to my original question.

Which leaves another question: why does this work without a temporary array?

Answer (score 0):

How about using `nonzero` to identify which elements are not zero?

```
x = np.ones((3,4))
s = sparse.csr_matrix((3,4))
s[0,0] = 2
s[1,2] = 3
I,J = s.nonzero()
x[:] = 0  # omit if just changing nonzero values
x[I,J] = s.data
x
```

`nonzero` functions the same for both dense and `csr` arrays.  I haven't tried it with the other formats.

---

For a csr (and coo) sparse matrix, values are  stored the `s.data` array.  In this example it looks like:

```
array([ 2.,  4.])
```

`x` values are in a `data` buffer, `x.data`.  In this case it is 12 contiguous floats.

```
x.ravel()
# array([ 2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  4.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

There's no way that those 2 values of `s` can be mapped on to the 12 values of `x` without copying.  The sparse data values do not, in general, match with a contiguous block of values in its dense equivalent.

You worry about the size of the `I` and `J` arrays.  If the sparse matrix was in `coo` format, its `row` and `col` attributes could be used in the same way:

```
sc=s.tocoo()
x[sc.row, sc.col]=sc.data
```

But converting from one sparse format to another involves copying data.  And coo arrays are not subscriptable.

---

```
x = np.zeros((3,4))
x[:]=['123','321','0','1']
```

produces

```
array([[ 123.,  321.,    0.,    1.],
       [ 123.,  321.,    0.,    1.],
       [ 123.,  321.,    0.,    1.]])
```

It does apply `float` to each item one the right side, and then 'broadcasts' it to fit the `x` size.

The `[]` translates into a call to `-_setitem__`.

```
x.__setitem__((1,2),3)  # same as x[1,2]=3
x.__setitem__((None,2),'3') # sets the last row
```

It appears to call `float` on each item of any iterable (need to double check this).  But if the value is some other object, we get an error similar to your original one:

```
class Foo(): pass
x.__setitem__((1,2), Foo())
# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Foo'
```

sparse `coo` and `dok` formats produce a similar error, while `csr` and `lil` produce a

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I haven't figured out which method or attribute of the sparse matrix is being used here.

Take a look at `np.broadcast`.  I think that replicates the kind of iteration used in these assignments.

```
b = np.broadcast(x[:], [1,2,3,4])
list(b)
```

We could remove the float conversion complication by starting with an array with dtype object, which can hold anything:

```
xa=np.zeros((3,4), dtype=object)
xa[:]=s
```

But now `s` appears in each element of `xa`.  It hasn't distributed the values of `s` over `xa`.

I am guessing that when `s` is not an `np.array`, `numpy` first wraps it when doing the assignment, e.g.:

```
x[:] = np.array(s)
```

When `s` is a scalar, or list, this produces an array that can be broadcast to fit `x`.  But when it is an object (a sparse array is not a numpy array), this wrapping is just a 0d array with dtype=object.  You need to pass `s` through a function that turns it into an iterable that can be broadcast.  The most obvious one is `toarray()`.

Comment: This would avoid copying the whole matrix into a new array, but it would still need to create new intermediate arrays (`I` and `J`).

Comment: Also, it would need extra code for the sparse case. I would really like to keep the `a[:] = s` part as is and solve the problem by *somehow manipulating* `s` beforehand.

Comment: By 'manipulating s', do you mean filling in the zero elements, so they can be copied over to `a` without special indexing?

Comment: How to manipulate `s` is the part which I don't know ... I just want to do something to `s` which makes the following `a[:] = s` work. To be more specific (an I left this part out in my original question), I want to slice into `s` and it should still work: `a[:] = s[start:stop]`. So basically I need something that stores sparse data and allows slicing and assignment of the result to NumPy arrays without making a copy of the data.

Comment: I added some notes on data layout in sparse arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm aware that the values will be copied on assignment, what I want to avoid are any additional and *unnecessary* copies and the corresponding potential memory allocations. What I want to do is basically copy the values one by one. But I want this to happen automatically during `a[:] = s`.

Comment: To do one-by-one copies fast you need to drop down to `c` code, such as by using `cython`.

Comment: I updated my original question with one way to *somehow manipulate* `s`. I can avoid the original error message, but sadly, I don't get much further ...

Comment: I think being able to iterate through the values of the right hand side is more important than converting to float.

Comment: I think the key point is that the sparse matrices are not recognized as sequences by `PySequence_Check()`. I updated my question accordingly.